# How to replace the value that include infinity?

Tags: replacement, conditional, character-encoding

Good day,

I have the output A and I want to do some operation to A:

```
A = {0, 1, 2}
B = -Total[(#*Log2[#]& /@ A]
```

when i run, has error :

```
Indeterminate expression 0 (-\[Infinity]) encountered. >>
```

How can I edit the coding, if I want to use

```
If output A=0, the value of #*Log2[#]=0
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Do a check:

```
If[# == 0, 0, # Log2[#]] & /@ A
```

Or, you don't have to know the limiting value(s) beforehand:

```
Limit[x Log2[x], x -> #] & /@ A
```

#### Update: holding evaluation

```
hold = Hold[# Log2[#]] & /@ A
```

> {Hold[0 Log2[0]], Hold[1 Log2[1]], Hold[2 Log2[2]]}

```
ReleaseHold[hold /. HoldPattern[0 Log2[0]] -> 0]
```

> {0, 0, 2}

Comment: I want to substitute the value of 0Log2(0) as 0. Thank you, I do it first.

Comment: @munirah In that case you shouldn't let `Log2[0]` evaluate.

Comment: @munirah, that's what the `If[]` is for; an alternative would be to use `Piecewise[]`.

Comment: @munirah Version 10 features inactivated expressions which might be interesting to you.

Comment: thank you for helping me, I understand it now

Comment: @Bole.. it means?