# Extension question on How to replace the value that include infinity?

Tags: functions, replacement, conditional

Based on earlier question [How to replace the value that include infinity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123125/how-to-replace-the-value-that-include-infinity/123126#123126),

Now, If I have the input A

```
A= {-3, 0, 1,2}
```

and do the operation :

```
B = -Total[(#*Log2[#]& /@ A]
```

Hence, I do

```
If[# == 0, 0, # Log2[#]] & /@ A
hold = Hold[# Log2[#]] & /@ A
ReleaseHold[hold /. HoldPattern[0 Log2[0]] -> 0]
```

to replace 0.

Now, 
how can I not enter a negative number in the calculation in B. In other words, B only calculates the positive number and [0 Log2[0]] -> 0.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
B = -Total[If[# > 0, (#*Log2[#]), 0] & /@ A]
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond. It try it by puting the given expression in last line and i get {-((3*(I*Pi + Log[3]))/Log[2]), 0, 0, 2} and the answer is -2. the answers is correct, but I want to know, the output of negative value is just expression and not include in calculation right?

Answer (score 4):

For the kind of operation you appear to be doing I typically write a customized function to replace the built-in, here `Log2`.  Basically:

```
Attributes[pLog2] = Listable;

pLog2[x_?NonPositive] := 0
pLog2[x_?NumericQ] := Log2[x]

Format[pLog2[x_]] := HoldForm @ Subscript[Log2, p][x]
```

Now:

```
#*pLog2[#] & /@ {-3, 0, 1, 2}
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 2}
> ```

And also:

```
#*pLog2[#] & @ {-3, 0, 1, 2, Pi, x}
```

[image]

I included the formatting rule just to illustrate what is possible.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me. I already run it but how can I do if I want to substitute the list {-3,0,1,2} as A not the list.?

Comment: @munirah I may misunderstand but I think you mean simply `A = {-3, 0, 1, 2}` and then on another line `-Total[#*pLog2[#] & @ A]`, or just `-Total[A*pLog2[A]]`.  By the way it is best *not* to start user Symbol names (like `A`) with capital letters, as these may conflict with built-ins, e.g. `C`, `D`, `E`, `I, `N` are all existing reserved Symbols.

Comment: It mean when I want to make any, it better for me use small letter?Here, I try to replace the symbol A instead the list {-3, 0, 1, 2} since the list can be variety. hence,  I do like this : -Total[#*pLog2[#] & @ A] but iit come error

Comment: @munirah: in short, *always* use `a` instead of `A`, `c` instead of `C`, etc. as your variables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my proposal:

```
ClearAll[xlgx];
xlgx[x_] := x * Log2[(1 - UnitStep[-x]) (x - 1) + 1];
```

Or adapting Mr.Wizard's approach, just "truncating" the logarithm:

```
ClearAll[pLog2];
pLog2[x_] := Log2[(1 - UnitStep[-x]) (x - 1) + 1];
```

*Examples:*

OP's:

```
-Total@xlgx[{-3, 0, 1, 2}]
(*  -2  *)
```

Vectorized:

```
xlgx[Range[-4, 4, 2]]
(*  {0, 0, 0, 2, 8}  *)
```

Preserves packed arrays (provided output is machine-sized):

```
xlgx[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*  True  *)

xlgx[2^Range[0, 57]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*  True  *)
```

Valid values:

```
input = RandomReal[{-1, 10}, 10000];
xlgx[input] == (# Log2[#] /. x_?(Not@*Developer`MachineRealQ) :> 0. & /@ input)
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing . i so new in mathematica. I will learn it slowly. It too complex to me to understand

Comment: @munirah Yeah, there is *a lot* to learn.  Fortunately you can still do a lot even with a little knowledge.  Try your best to learn on your own using resources like [(18)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121), but do not hesitate to ask Questions when you run into trouble.

Comment: thank you very much @Mr. Wizard. I learn a lot and improve from this forum. People inside here help me very much. From zero I learn and learn and will learn .